# Mermaid Flowchart does not render 'longer arrows'

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, diagrammer

````
---
title: "Markdown Demo"
author: "J"
date: "6/14/2021"
output: html_document
---

## Setup
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(DiagrammeR)
```

## R Markdown

```{r}

mermaid("
  graph TB;
    a ==> b; 
    b ----> c[apple]
    
                    
")
```
````

For some reason the 2nd line in the graph doesn't seem to be rendering because its not realizing the 'longer arrow'. Anyone know how to solve this trivial problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this depends on how large your network graph is. You can look up the documentation of the package in Rstudio by entering `??DiagrammeR::mermaid` in the console.

An example from the [package](https://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/graphviz_and_mermaid.html) shows 10 nodes creates longer arrows than just A->B

Doesn't look like `b ----> c[apple]` is proper syntax for longer arrows, to what I read in the package docs.

```
grViz("
digraph a_nice_graph {

# node definitions with substituted label text
node [fontname = Helvetica]
a [label = '@@1']
b [label = '@@2-1']
c [label = '@@2-2']
d [label = '@@2-3']
e [label = '@@2-4']
f [label = '@@2-5']
g [label = '@@2-6']
h [label = '@@2-7']
i [label = '@@2-8']
j [label = '@@2-9']

# edge definitions with the node IDs
a -> {b c d e f g h i j}
}

[1]: 'top'
[2]: 10:20
")
```

[image]

Comment: I believe in your example your mixing up DiagrammeR::Graphviz with DiagrammeR::Mermaid which are different packages. In terms of the mermaid package, its possible so I'm not quite sure how to implement it into the R script. I've seen someone do it before with an older version of R.

You can see that's its possible under the heading "Minimum length of a link" in the mermaid documentation.
https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/flowchart?id=links-between-nodes

Comment: Your code is telling me different, you loaded `library(DiagrammeR)` which loads the package into memory, and then you are calling the `mermaid` function within that package, hence the `package::function` syntax. But The link you posted is for Javascript and Markdown, unfortunately I am not a javascript person, I would suggest adding "javascript" tag to your question to see if you could get some Javascript devs to look at your question.